# Is there a way to keep an icon added to .fc-event-title when click-dragging an event in Full Calendar v6.0.2?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I have a feature where I allow users to flag an appointment as missed. When doing so, I add an icon to the event so that it is obvious in the agenda:

[image]

This is done by leveraging `eventRender`:

```js
if (event.extendedProps.isMissed === true) {
  var message = "<i class='fas fa-calendar-times pull-right' title='Rendez-vous non honoré'></i>";
  element.find('.fc-event-title').prepend(message);
}
```

This works fine, until I click'n'drag the event to move it, in which case the icon is lost when I release the click:

[image]

The `<i>` is element is removed from `.fc-event-title`.

Is there a way to keep it?

Comment: This feels like an internal bug to me. There's probably not much we can do about it here. You'd be better to report it to the fullcalendar project directly, following the instructions at https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs